# Python pycrypto module: why simplejson can't dumps encrypted string?

Tags: python, pycrypto

It shows **UnicodeError:** `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: unexpected code byte`

Here is code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import simplejson as json

key = '0123456789abcdef'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(key, mode)
text = '1010101010101010'

json.dumps(encryptor.encrypt(text))
```

How to avoid this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cipher usually generates non-printable binary data. It is not possible for json to dump non-printable characters.

One solution could be to use base64 encoding prior to json dump:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import simplejson as json
import base64

key = '0123456789abcdef'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(key, mode)
text = '1010101010101010'

json.dumps(base64.encodestring(encryptor.encrypt(text)))
```

Similarly, before decryption, you'll have to decode base64 as well.