# Python: Can JSON be used to send a message to a Python Server which contains encrypted sections?

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

I don't know much about JSON yet, I just started following this tutorial, so please bear with me:

http://pymotw.com/2/json/

My question is can I use JSON to send messages that contain a section that is encrypted to a Python server so it can forward it to another server?

The message will come from a Javascript client over SSL containing some info for the Python Server and an Encrypted message to be forwarded to another Python Server. The message will look like:

`{ref_obj { msg_obj }_pub_k }_SSL`

Is this possible? I saw this post:

[Python pycrypto module: why simplejson can't dumps encrypted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863423/python-pycrypto-module-why-simplejson-cant-dumps-encrypted-string)

If this cannot be done with JSON, can someone advise how it should be done? The only requirement I have is that the original message has to come from a Javascript client (as it will be a plugin in Chrome) and go to a Python Server for forwarding.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

but certain strings must be escaped prior to sending it and then unescaped at the other end.
Either by `from base64 import b64encode, b64decode` or something similar.

The reasons for this is that the JSON data MUST be string or int values, nothing else basicly.

`json.dumps({1 : 2, 'hey' : 'you'})` will work and that's the format you need to keep it. meaning binary data might mess with json as it expects "normal" strings. b64encode ensures that it's only valid characters in the string and nothing else :)

Depending on what you're trynig to acomplish.
You can also encrypt the entire JSON string and send that to the server, decrypt it and parse it as JSON.

See the encryption as a tunnel.

JSON -> encrypt(JSON-string) -> server -> decrypted -> parse JSON

Or if you need the JSON data as meta data, do the first option.

## This is a way to encapsulate ALL traffic as "encrypted"

```
def encrypt(s):
    encryptedString = AES.encrypt(s)
    return b64encode(encryptedString)

sock.connect(server)
jsondata = {1 : 2}
sock.send( encrypt(json.dumps(jsondata)) )
```

And on the server you just do:

```
data = sock.recv(1024)
jsondata = json.loads( b64decode(decrypt(data))) )
print(jsondata)
```

## This is a way to encrypt only SOME parts of the json data:

```
def encrypt(s):
    encryptedString = AES.encrypt(s)
    return b64encode(encryptedString)

sock.connect(server)
jsondata = {1 : encrypt(2)}
sock.send( json.dumps(jsondata) )
```

And on the server:

```
data = sock.recv(1024)
jsondata = json.loads(data)
jsondata[1] = decrypt(b64decode(jsondata[1]))
```

Comment: I got a few questions. Would this work if I am not to decrypt the encrypted part in the first server? I am not quite sure if I made myself clear. The communication is tunnelled through Server1, like: Client -> Server1 -> Server2
So Server1 only has to be able to open part of the message, when I call json.dump() will that keep the encrypted section OK so I can forward it to Server2?

Comment: Yepp, it will. But you can't use my first option then (ALL traffic) because that would mean that Server1 would have to decrypt the entire block (easier to get right tho).

See my second example where i only encrypt the value `2` and then i forward the data to Server1, this way Server1 can access `1` but the value of it will be encrypted.. this is useful if you only want Server1 to see the recipient of the message and the value to that recipient is encrypted :)

Comment: Your last edit is definitely what I am after! Thanks a lot for the very thorough answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply encrypt the JSON and send the ciphertext as raw binary data.

JSON is just a format; no-one is forcing you to send it over the wire.

Comment: sorry I am not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean to encode my message with JSON for the unencrypted part and then send the rest a a binary? Can that be done in all one transmission? How do separate the JSON part from the binary part at the Python Server?

Comment: @unixsnob: Why not send the entire JSON payload as binary ciphertext?

Comment: Because I need give the 1st server some info about the message being forwarded for accounting purposes. I think the solution given by Torxed is what I am after. Thanks for the help anyway.